# web-ext connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5037

Tags: node.js, tcp, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-ext

I am creating firefox extension, and trying to test using official firefox documentation here:
https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/developing-extensions-for-firefox-for-android/#install-and-run-your-extension-in-firefox-for-android

When I try to run the command:
web-ext run -t firefox-android --adb-device XXX --firefox-apk org.mozilla.fenix

It throws me this error:
[image]

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5037
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16)

Error code: ECONNREFUSED

I have done everything, turned off my firewall. Yet no success..

Comment: you are sure developer mode is enabled on Android and "Allow Device Debugging" was confirmed on phone?

Comment: yes it is enabled, 
And also inside firefox-android nightly , remote debugging is ON

Comment: Update: In windows, it's not working, in Ubuntu, it worked .. lol.

Answer (score -2):

Update -
In windows, it didn't work.
In ubuntu (wsl), it worked

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31579795)